# Derivative of ${ x }^{ x }$ without logarithmic differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

With logarithmic differentiation, it is quite simple to compute the derivative of $x^x$:

> $$y=x^x$$
>    $$\ln {y} =x \ln{x}$$
>    $$\frac {1}{y} \frac {dy}{dx} = \ln{x} +1$$
>    $$\frac {dy}{dx} =\left( ln(x)+1 \right) x^x.$$

**Is there a method to compute the derivative of ${ x }^{ x }$ that does not rely on logarithmic differentiation?**

Comment: Sort of: you can rewrite $x^x$ as $e^{x\ln x}$ and differentiate that. But the computations are essentially identical.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I should have thought of that! I'll type up an answer.

Comment: You should be able to do it via first-principles right? Although its definitely not a better method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Brian M. Scott for the comment that led to this solution:

$y={ x }^{ x }={ e }^{ x\ln { x }  }\\ \frac { dy }{ dx } =\left( \ln(x)+1 \right) { e }^{ x\ln { x }  }\\ \frac { dy }{ dx } =\left( \ln(x)+1 \right) { x }^{ x }\\ $

Comment: Logarithmic differentiation and this one is essentially the same.

Answer (score 9):

There's another way that looks like a gross blunder but actually is perfectly correct. I will illustrate it on the more general question, differentiate $y=f(x)^{g(x)}$.

If $g$ were constant, we'd get $f'(x)g(x)f(x)^{g(x)-1}$.

If $f$ were constant, we'd get $g'(x)f(x)^{g(x)}\log f(x)$.

Add these together to get the answer: $$y'=f'(x)g(x)f(x)^{g(x)-1}+g'(x)f(x)^{g(x)}\log f(x)$$

It's easy to see that in the original problem, where $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x$, this reduces to $x^x+x^x\log x$, as obtained by other methods.

Comment: Why did you add them together?

Comment: @AGo, mostly because it works.

Comment: Yeah , i meant why does it work?

Comment: @AGo, I think it's an application of a version of the chain rule. If $y$ is a function of $s$ and $t$, each of which is a function of $x$, then $dy/dx=(\partial y/\partial s)(ds/dx)+(\partial y/\partial t)(dt/dx)$. Here we have $y=s^t$ with $s=f(x)$, $t=g(x)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: it *is* an application of the chain rule (no doubt about it)

Comment: (+1) this is not logarithmic differentiation (or at least it is so deeply hidden that it is quite hard to see). To me, this answers the question better than differentiating $e^{x\log(x)}$.

Comment: What's funny about this approach is that it's the sum of the very things we tell first-semester calculus students _not_ to do when differentiating a variable raised to a function exponent.  But in fact this is the correct "general rule" for which the "Power Rule" (variable raised to constant) and the "exponential function rule" (constant raised to variable) are special cases...